# Yii set value for textarea in tablular input model

Tags: yii, textarea

I have the form field as

```
$form->textArea($model,'remarks[1]');
```

Here I have to set value for this textarea.

How to do this? I am new to this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$model` is your model and `remarks[1]` is your attribute, you can specify the value using:

> $model->remarks[1] = 'Your Value';

Edit:

Try:

```
$model->remarks = 'Your Value';
$form->textArea($model,'[1]remarks');
```

Comment: What do you mean by incremented value? What is your model? What is your attribute? If you just want to display a textArea, you can use CHtml::textArea(string $name, string $value='').